# How can I `ssh root@localhost` and `su root` without password on macOS?

Tags: macos, ssh

Before asking this question, I have searched other solutions and done the following things:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsaK.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. Enable root account on Mac, and set password to empty
3. `su root`, it prints out "Sorry", so I `passwd root` to a non-empty password
4. Now `su root` works, but still need password. I don't want this, I want to log in without type any password(Yes, it is not neat, I will check how to improve this later)
5. `ssh root@localhost` fails with the following

   ```
   ssh root@localhost
   Password:
   Password:
   Password:
   root@localhost's password: 
   Permission denied, please try again.
   root@localhost's password: 
   Received disconnect from ::1 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
   Disconnected from ::1 port 22
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your public key into `root`'s authorised keys. Then you should be able to `ssh root@localhost` without a password.

For example (make sure root has a password first):

```sh
ssh-copy-id root@localhost
# <enter root's password>

ssh root@localhost
# should log in without password
# (unless your private key is password protected, in which case, it will
# still ask for that one)
```

Keep in mind, some setups of SSH server forbid logging in as root. Check the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and make sure `PermitRootLogin` is set to `yes`. If it's not listed anywhere in the file, just add `PermitRootLogin yes` on a line by itself (typically, anywhere in this file will do).

Comment: Hi @dreamlax, I tried, however still needs password. it prints out the [following messages](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hNKjBZ2n8d/).

Comment: However, by setting PermitRootLogin to yes, I can ssh root@localhost, with password

Comment: I have found out why, I must use `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@localhost`